# iOS - setValue:forUndefinedKey problem on a subView

Tags: ios, ios4, subview, xcode4.2

This looks like a basic IB error but it hasn't worked out to be.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught execption 'NSUnknownKeyExecption', reason:'[<TrailersViewController 0x585e8e0> setValue:forUndfinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myImageView.'
```

1. myImageView isn't in TrailersViewController it's in
   another object that is on TrailersViewController.
2. myImageView does not have any IBOutlets.
3. Third it seems that you can have this problem when pushing view
   controllers but it's object is shown in a subview.
4. myImageView is just a local variable in the object.

Also I had this working but noticed my TrailersViewController was rather leaky so I'm re-organizing it to stop those leaks.

I'm at a loss at the moment but any other directions I could head in would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have associated the myImageView view in the nib to a @property IBOutlet called myImageView inside TrailersViewController, but you have forgot to @synthesize this property.
So when the runtime tries to assign the myImageView object loaded from nib to the myImageView instance using key-value approach it doesn't find the setter method has you didn't synthesize it.

Comment: I had renamed an @property away from myImageView that did reside on TrailersViewController but I renamed everything and started a new NIB from scratch. To try and avoid that.

Deep sixing it again... just to be sure.

Comment: Deleting the Nib (I only have one in my project) and re-creating it didn't fix it and "@property IBOutlet myImageView" isn't any where in my project anymore

That particular variable is only used in 3 places. :(

Comment: I've completely coded it out of the project now... and it is still giving me the same error...

Comment: Deleting the App from the simulator and device fixed the problem... >.>

Comment: It did not work.  there is the same error.  Thankyou for the suggestion though